# Getting error object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic =

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting error :

`object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean, partition = 0, offset = 200, CreateTime = 1538416446690, checksum = 3419013820, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 113, key = null, value = [B@4e41c53e))
- element of array (index: 0).`

This consumer code gets the data from producer which has key as string and value as AVRO serialized in Java based code.  no data is coming even CreateDataStream is also not working. at some points I see ArrayoutofBound error also.Same code is working fine for one of my friend. I am using kafka010 as I have SSL protocol so cannot use kafka old versions. I tried with all deserialize options in comment below but nothing worked. There is no output for stream variable also.

`KafkaConsumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");`

Here is my code.

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, JField, JObject, JString, JValue}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, LogManager, Logger}
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils, LocationStrategies}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.io._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericData, GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject
//import org.json.simple.JSONObject

object ScalaJsonTest extends java.io.Serializable {

  val runNum = 789
  val hdfsPath = s"HDFS PATH put here"

//  val schemaStr =
//    """{
//  "type": "record",
//  "name": "b24_ptlf_financial_formatted",
//  "fields": [
//  {
//    "name": "AuthorizationTransactionSource",
//    "type": "string"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "AuthorizationTransactionSourceID",
//    "type": "string"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TransactionTimestamp",
//    "type": {
//      "type": "long",
//      "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
//    }
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TerminalDate",
//    "type": {
//      "type": "int",
//      "logicalType": "date"
//    }
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TerminalTime",
//    "type": {
//      "type": "int",
//      "logicalType": "time-millis"
//    }
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "MonerisCustomerNumber",
//    "type": "string"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "DeviceNumber",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "string"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "PrimaryAccountNumberPrefix",
//    "type": "string"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "PrimaryAccountNumberSuffix",
//    "type": "string"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TransactionApprovedFlag",
//    "type": "boolean"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TransactionAmount",
//    "type": "long"
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TransactionCurrency",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "string"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "MerchantSettlementAmount",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "long"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "MerchantSettlementCurrency",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "string"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "TransactionTypeCode",
//    "type": {
//      "type": "enum",
//      "name": "TransactionTypeCode",
//      "symbols": [
//      "PURC",
//      "AUTH",
//      "COMP",
//      "RFND"
//      ]
//    }
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "PointOfSaleEntryMode",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "string"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "ElectronicCommerceIndicator",
//    "type": [
//    "null",
//    "string"
//    ],
//    "default": null
//  },
//  {
//    "name": "InternalCardFingerprint",
//    "type": "string"
//  }
//  ]
//}""""
val schemaRegistryURL = "http://vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:8081"
  val topics = "b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean"
  val subjectValueName = topics + "-value"

  val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)

  val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)

  //Use Avro parsing classes to get Avro Schema
  val parser = new Schema.Parser
  val topicValueAvroSchema: Schema = parser.parse(valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema)
 // val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr)



  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     {
      Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
      val log = LogManager.getRootLogger
      log.setLevel(Level.WARN)
      val props = Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers" -> 
        "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
        "schema.registry.url" -> ,
        "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  //       "value.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
         "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
        //"key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
       // "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
        "group.id" -> "b24_ptlf_eim_processing" ,
        "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
        "ssl.keystore.location" -> "C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\old keys\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\kafka-eim-dev.jks",
        "ssl.keystore.password" -> ,
        "ssl.key.password" -> ,
        "ssl.truststore.location" -> "C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\old keys\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\cpbp-ca-dev.jks",
        "ssl.truststore.password" -> "iB>3v$6m@9",
        "ssl.keystore.type" -> "JCEKS",
        "ssl.truststore.type" -> "JCEKS"
      )

      val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaConsumer").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate
      val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
      val subscribeStrategy = ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, Array[Byte]](Array("b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean"), props)
      val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, subscribeStrategy)
      print(topicValueAvroSchema)
      stream.print()
      val result = stream.map(record => {
        val outVal = parseRecord(record.value)
        /*if(outVal != null) {

            outVal
          }*/

        outVal
      })

        result.print()
        //      result.foreachRDD((rdd, batchtime) => {
//        val outPath = hdfsPath + "/" + batchtime.milliseconds
//        rdd.saveAsTextFile(outPath)
//        val df = sc.createDataFrame(rdd, getSchema())
//       df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("csv").save(outPath)
//      })

      ssc.start()

      Thread.sleep(60 * 1000)

      //    ssc.awaitTermination()
      ssc.stop()
      sc.stop()
      sc.close()
    }

  }


  def parseRecord(message: Array[Byte]): String = {

    var opTypeStr = ""
    var jsonRow = new JSONObject()
    var binRow2 = ""
    var binRow = ""

     {

      val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericData.Record](topicValueAvroSchema)

      val decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory

      val binaryDecoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(message, null)


      val binRow: String = reader.read(null, binaryDecoder).toString


      binRow
    }
  }

  def getSchema1(): StructType = {
    {


      StructType(List(
        StructField("table", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed1", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed2", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed3", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed4", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed5", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed6", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed7", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed8", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed9", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed10", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed11", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed12", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed13", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed14", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed15", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed16", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed17", StringType, true),
        StructField("Filed18", StringType, true)

      ))
    }
        StructType(List(
          StructField("table", StringType, true),
          StructField("Field1", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed2", StringType, true),
          StructField("Field3", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed4", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed5", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed6", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed7", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed8", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed9", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed10", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed11", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed12", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed13", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed14", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed15", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed16", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed17", StringType, true),
          StructField("Filed18", StringType, true)

        ))
      }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the full exception? And why aren't you using Structured Streaming if you already have an Avro structure?

Comment: Note: Avro generic decoder has no relation to Schema Registry, and it won't work unless you get the actual schema from the registry and skip the schema ID in the message bytes. Also, why do you have an extra curly bracket inside parseRecord?